# In C#, how can I access an object's objects when bracket notation doesn't work?

Tags: c#, object

I have an object of objects, and I'm not sure how to access the values. Here's a picture from the VS debugger:

[image: Debugger shows objects]

the object in question is bounds. I'd like to get the value 7, 14, 157 and 174 like so:

```
bounds[0]  //Should equal 7
bounds[3]  //Should equal 174
```

Obviously this won't work  because it's not an array but an object of objects. Could you explain the correct way to access the numeric values nested inside the bounds object?

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly is bounds declared?  Do you mean it's an array of objects?  As in "object[] bounds; "?  No - you said its not - so what exactly is bounds?

Comment: @The Evil Greebo: It's an array of boxed doubles `{object[]}`, boxed as an `object` itself. So Greg has it right, you need to unbox twice.

Comment: Sorry i don't get what you mean by "object of objects" could you post the code where you initialized bounds? Just a wild guess ((object[])bounds)[0]?

Comment: @dowhilefor - In the last column of the screenshot, you can see that the variable type is `object` but the value of the variable is an `object[]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to cast `bounds` from `object` to `object[]`, get the value from the array, then cast it to `double`.

```
object[] array = (object[])bounds;
object value = array[0];
double number = (double)value;
```

or one line

```
double value = (double)((object[])bounds)[0];
```

If you put your numbers in an array of double in the first place, then you can avoid all the casting.

```
double[] bounds = new double[x];
... populate array
double value = bounds[0];
```

Also, "bracket notation" is know as [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Comment: It's like [pass the parcel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_parcel), except you're the only player :/

Comment: @Greg- Thanks for the quick reply.
double value = (double)((object[])bounds[0]) yields: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @Hairgami_Master - Err, I put a parenthesis in the wrong place. It's fixed now. Computers are so picky!

Comment: @Greg= I hate computers. They can be so persnickety. However, your answer worked! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this. I can press on to the next great challenge.

Comment: @ Greg - you're a lifesaver. Bumped my head against the window for days over this. Thanks